# Json request data and jquery prettyphoto binding issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, html, dom

There is a situation I am having with jQuery. In particular its prettyPhoto library and getJSON function.

I have a page which loads HTML, it calls jQuery and prettyPhoto. There is some inline JS which makes a JSON request further down the page:

**It should work like the below:**

1) Page loads,

2) Javascript code run,

3) Script runs a jQuery JSON request which returns and has HTML (a-tags and images inside each a-tag) inside,

4) Script then prints the HTML from inside the JSON to the screen,

5) User clicks  a-tag/image and it opens in prettyPhoto's iframe popup.

NOTE -> Each a-tag has a prettyPhoto id attached (to load the image in prettyPhoto using iframe popup).

The problem is the images (a-links) do not open with prettyPhoto and I am not sure why. There is no JS Error.

However, it does work if i manually have the HTML (a-links/image) already there (so just loading their HTML from the JSON request seems to make the difference).

Seems by time the JSON request returns (with  HTML) prettyphoto already binds to a-tags (or lack off).

**Tested so far:**

Tried putting JSON request in 'document.ready' and prettyPhoto in 'window.load'. So does JSON requests early and prettyPhoto binds when everything else loads - failed

Tried using jQuery AJAX instead of JSON - failed

Dont need the code especially but having trouble with the logic.

Comment: It is helpful when asking a question to include your code so that it's easier to help you debug. It sounds like you need help making your code run asynchronously, so that the prettyPhoto stuff only gets called when the JSON request is complete.

Comment: I was going to but I wasnt sure if there was a gap in my understanding of page events and jquery events. i will try to do it next time i have an issue. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the HTML from the JSON (a-links/images) doesnt come back quick enough (before 'window.load' runs).

Try putting the prettyPhoto JS into the success callback (i.e. where returns data).

Below load_images.json is the JSON request you do which returns the HTML (a-links and their images):

```
$.getJSON("load_html.json", function() {
    //grab HTML data (images/a-links) from json file and print into page
})
.success(function() { 
    //JS code running prettyPhoto inside here. Now will bind to a-links.
});
```

PrettyPhoto now binds to A-links AFTER the JSON has loaded them.

Hopefully will help having the prettyPhoto stuff AFTER the a-links.

If that fails try putting the prettyPhoto code inside the complete callback which occurs after success callback. Like the below:

```
$.getJSON("load_html.json", function() {
    //grab HTML data (images/a-links) from json file and print into page
})
.success(function() { 
    //nothing
})
.complete(function() {
     //JS code running prettyPhoto inside here. Now will bind to a-links.
});
```

This way you are giving prettyPhoto plenty of time to bind to the correct a-links which are marked for it.

Try that.

Comment: I tried that and it works. your a life saver, great idea. thanks